# La consulta no muestra los datos relacionados correctamente

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo un pequeño proyecto y me atore con lo siguiente: Tengo 2 tablas, una llamada toners y otra areas la cual los toners pueden tener una área y quiero que en lugar de mostrar la llave foránea del area que tiene el toner muestre el nombre de dicha área. Si Muestra el nombre, pero no muestra el nombre correspondiente al id. **Recalco que no muestra el nombre correspondiente al id**

**Controlador Toner**

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $datos['Toners'] = Toner::paginate(20);
    $areas = Areas::with('Toners')->get();
    return view('Toners.index', $datos, compact('areas'));
}
```

**Modelo Areas**

```
class Areas extends Model{
//
protected $primaryKey='id_area';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = ['nombre_area' , 'responsable_area' , 'correo_resp_area'];

public function toners()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Toner', 'id_toner', 'id_area');
}
```

}

**Modelo Toner**

```
class Toner extends Model{
//
protected $primaryKey='id_toner';
public $timestamps = false;

public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Areas');
}
```

}

**Vista para mostrar los datos**

```
@foreach ($areas as $area)
            @foreach ($area->Toners as $Toner)
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                    <td>{{$Toner->marca}}</td>
                    <td>{{$Toner->modelo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$Toner->referencia}}</td>
                    <td>{{$Toner->cantidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$area->nombre_area}}</td>
                    <td>{{$Toner->fecha_entrega}}</td>
                    <td>${{$Toner->precio_unitario}}</td>
                    <td>${{$Toner->total}}</td>
                    <td>

                        <a href="{{url('/Toners/'.$Toner->id_toner.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="far fa-edit"></span> Editar </a>

                        <form method="post" action="{{url('/Toners/'.$Toner->id_toner)}}" style="display: inline">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿Eliminar éste Registro?');" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <span class="fas fa-trash"></span> Eliminar</button>
                        </form>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

**Por ultimo vista del navegador**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu modelo `Areas` ¿cuál es la llave foránea?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error parte de esta línea y de los argumentos que le pasas:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Toner', 'id_toner', 'id_area');
```

Si revisas la [doc.oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), nos indica que: el segundo y tercer argumento nos sirven para anular la llave foránea y primaria (*si es que estas no siguen las convenciones esperadas por Eloquent*) y pasar valores necesarios para cada una de estas.

Sin embargo tu código parece no estar respetando ese *orden*, dado lo cual te sugiero lleves a cabo los cambios necesarios considerando este ejemplo:

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\Toner', 'llave_foranea_en_toner', 'llave_primaria_modelo_Areas');
```

Ahora para el caso de la relación inversa (*igualmente solo si no se apegan a las convenciones esperadas por Eloquent*) tendrías igualmente que considerar evaluar si estás pasando los argumentos no solo necesarios sino adecuados, mira:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Areas', 'llave_foranea_en_toner', 'llave_primaria_en_areas');
```

**Lectura de interés**

- [Convenciones de modelos en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)